# Поиск в древовидной структуре

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, search, treeview

Опытные коллеги кто сталкивался с такой древовидной структурой [Bootstrap tree view](https://codepen.io/axelaredz/pen/vrLENZ) как лучше всего организовать по ней поиск, если дерево очень большое, чтобы при использования поиска открывалась именно нужная ветка и элемент.

```
<div class="tree well">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span><i class="icon-folder-open"></i> Theme</span> <a href="">ссылки место</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Standard</span> <a href=""></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Grand Child</span> <a href="">ссылки место</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Child</span> <a href=""></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Grand Child</span> <a href=""></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Grand Child</span> <a href="">ссылки место</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Great Grand Child</span> <a href=""></a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Great great Grand Child</span> <a href=""></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Great great Grand Child</span> <a href=""></a>
                                        </li>
                                     </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Great Grand Child</span> <a href=""></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Great Grand Child</span> <a href=""></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Grand Child</span> <a href=""></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span><i class="icon-folder-open"></i> Parent2</span> <a href=""></a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Child</span> <a href=""></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

.tree {
    min-height:20px;
    padding:19px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#fbfbfb;
    border:1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)
}
.tree li {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 5px 0 5px;
    position:relative
}
.tree li::before, .tree li::after {
    content:'';
    left:-20px;
    position:absolute;
    right:auto
}
.tree li::before {
    border-left:1px solid #999;
    bottom:50px;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    width:1px
}
.tree li::after {
    border-top:1px solid #999;
    height:20px;
    top:25px;
    width:25px
}
.tree li span {
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:3px 8px;
    text-decoration:none
}
.tree li.parent_li>span {
    cursor:pointer
}
.tree>ul>li::before, .tree>ul>li::after {
    border:0
}
.tree li:last-child::before {
    height:30px
}
.tree li.parent_li>span:hover, .tree li.parent_li>span:hover+ul li span {
    background:#eee;
    border:1px solid #94a0b4;
    color:#000
}
$(function () {
    $('.tree li:has(ul)').addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Collapse this branch');
    $('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function (e) {
        var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
        if (children.is(":visible")) {
            children.hide('fast');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Expand this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-plus-sign').removeClass('icon-minus-sign');
        } else {
            children.show('fast');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Collapse this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-minus-sign').removeClass('icon-plus-sign');
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: а очень большое это сколько? обычно очень большое если, то подгружается по мере открытия узлов а не сразу. Если подгружать динамически,то и поиск формально не зависит вообще от этого дерева.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение есть, еще немного доработаю, но суть как в этом примере:

```
<input type="text" id="search" />

<style>
  .highlight {
    background: red;
  }
</style>

<script>
$(function(){
$('#search').on('keyup', function (){
  var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase()
  if (val) {
    $('ul li span').each(function(idx, obj){
      if ($(obj).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1)
        $(obj).addClass('highlight')
      else
        $(obj).removeClass('highlight')
    })
  }
  else
    $('ul li span').removeClass('highlight')
})
})
</script>
```